# mongodb extension is installed but icannot reflect changes in mongoDB console

Tags: php

I am using WAMP server 64bit as well as mongoDB 64 bit in my windows 7 machine.
I have successfully configured mongoDB on wamp server where php_info() page shows MongoDB Support Version 1.3.2RC1 enabled.But the problem faced by me is whenever I establish connection with mongoDB in php code the code runs but it does not reflect the changes in mongoDB console.Y is this so?

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient();
//$db = $connection->sample;

// select a collection:
//$collection = $db->first;
$collection = $connection->sample->test1;

$doc = array(
"name" => "MDB",
"type" => "database",
"count" => 2,
"info" => (object)array( "x" => 203, "y" => 102),
"versions" => array("0.9.7", "0.9.8", "0.9.9")
);

$collection->insert( $doc );

echo "Inserted successfully....";

$document = $collection->findOne();
var_dump( $document );

?>
```

the above code retrieves the inserted document as it is on browser.But in mongo.exe console there is no data inserted.
My default database is 'db'

Comment: Read this and update your question! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist (How did you ignore all these improving messages!?!)

Comment: sorry...i am updating my question please go through it